# What is the equivalent of Biblatex in Context?

Tags: biblatex, context, context-mkiv

1. How do I do bibliography in Context, that is more than just bibtex? In the [manual](http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf) there is no explanation of this. [Source code](http://gitorious.org/context/context/blobs/origin/tex/context/base/bibl-bib.lua) doesn't tell me much either...
2. Are there any "packages" that provide bibliography support? (If yes - where is that **place** where I can search for packages?)
3. Can I use biblatex in context?

Comment: See http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Bibliography_mkiv and http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Bibliography to get started.

Comment: Thanks @Aditya The second link says: "Please note that this information is relevant to mkii. If you are using mkiv, see Bibliography_mkiv." And unfortunately the mkiv page is only 2 paragraphs long :-( And it seems the example is using "Bibtex" only.

Comment: ConTeXt uses bibtex as a backend, but it also includes some code, formerly known as the bib module, which allows to set up the bibliography. See [the bib manual](http://modules.contextgarden.net/dl/bibmod-doc/doc/context/bib/bibmod-doc.pdf) for more details. But frankly, bibliography support is not well tested in ConTeXt and you'll soon encounter limitations and bugs. You cannot use biblatex with ConTeXt.

Comment: Most of the information in the bib manual is still relevant to MkIV. Can you give an example of a feature from biblatex that you need?

Comment: @Aditya Yes, `pagetotal` or `url` field for citing online works. Multi-volume books etc.. Basically anything that biblatex has and bibtex doesn't :-) like more flexible citation or bibliography formatting.

Comment: @drozzy: For someone who doesn't know biblatex, I have a hard time understanding what "biblatex has and bibtex doesn't". What does "more flexible citation or bibliography formatting mean"? Adding new fields like _pagetotal_ and _url_ are straight forward (or, at least were straight forward in MkII; I haven't used bibliography much in MkIV).

Comment: @Aditya For example if I want to cite using author-title style, or use unicode in my bibliographies. Customize how my bibliography at the end of the document looks - for example, say I want to emphasize the author's name (in bibtex it requires *special* language - in biblatex it's just regular latex commands!)

Comment: @Aditya Also, mkII is not really an option for me, as I have to use unicode in my work.

Comment: I am not saying that you use MkII; just that I have not used bibliography extensively with MkIV. In ConTeXt you can use tex files to change the look of your publications. Have a look at the bib manual and the `bibl-*.tex` files in the `tex/context/bib` directory.

Comment: It's fair to say that biblatex+biber backend can do a lot more than bibtex (complete multifield Unicode sorting with tailoring, customisable sorting schemes, customisable crossref inheritance, on the fly data modifications, custom data models plus a lot more). It is a shame biblatex doesn't work with context but that's a piece of work none of the biblatex maintainers have time to look at really. Personally, I don't know context enough to even begin to look at this.

Comment: @drozzy - Two things: (i) you can set up Context to work with Bibtex8 using `\setupbibtex[bibtex=bibtex8]` with the `bib` module (provided paths are correctly set up) to give Unicode; (ii) MkII works with Xetex, giving another path to native Unicode support, one you probably should avoid.  Supporting MLA is the more tricky of your requirements.

Comment: There is also the `librarian` package, which does bibliography stuff without `bibtex`, and can be used with `ConTeXt` via the normal `\usemodule[librarian]`.  Unfortunately, I've not used it myself (or `ConTeXt`).  It looks pretty neat, and I always mean to look into it, but never have the time....

Comment: @jon Any chance for a link? Thanks!

Comment: If you have TeX Live, you can do `texdoc librarian`; otherwise look on [CTAN](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/librarian) (download from [mirror](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/generic/librarian/)).

Comment: Wow, just skimmed through the [librarian](http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/generic/librarian/doc/generic/librarian/librarian-doc.pdf) doc - looks amazing. Why isn't it used more I wonder? Would be nice to have some styles (e.g. MLA) defined for it - I wonder if anyone did something like that before?

Comment: Oh look, here is an example: http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/generic/librarian/tex/generic/librarian/authoryear.tex

Comment: @drozzy Could you please write a self answer that summarizes what's been said in the comments?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use biblatex with ConTeXt.

ConTeXt uses bibtex as a backend, but it also includes some code, formerly
known as the bib module, which allows to set up the bibliography. See the [bib
manual](http://modules.contextgarden.net/dl/bibmod-doc/doc/context/bib/bibmod-doc.pdf)
for more details. Bibliography support is not well tested in ConTeXt, though.

Although it has some rough edges and limitations, bibliography support is
quite flexible in ConTeXt and you can change the appearance using TeX macros.

As others have mentioned, there's also the [librarian
package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/librarian), which might be
worth a try (I've never used it myself).